# Proof that the range of a map is determined by its behaviour on the boundary.

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, derivatives, differential-topology

Let f be a mapping from an open neighbourhood of the 3-dimensional unit ball to the 2-dimensional plane. Suppose that f is smooth (infinitely continuously differentiable on its domain) and regular (it's derivative, as a 2x3 matrix, has rank 2 everywhere).

I would like a proof, or informed hint, or counterexample, for the claim that the f restricted to the closed unit ball has the same range as f restricted to the unit sphere.

It is not difficult to construct a counterexample when f is allowed to be nonregular.

I have stated the problem for a mapping from 3 to 2 dimensions but there may be a similar problem going from n to n-1 dimensions. For n=2 the proof is trivial: a regular differentiable mapping from the closed unit disk to the line reaches its maximum on the boundary circle.

Comment: I don't believe the n=2 case. What is this trivial proof? Are you really thinking of harmonic functions?

Comment: I suspected that there might be some topological trick similar to one of the forms of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem (a.k.a. the ham sandwich). But then I got bogged down trying to construct meaningful mappings between spheres. Regularity of $f$ means that the gradients of its two components are never parallel; perhaps something can be done with their vector product, which is never 0?

Comment: @nayrb With the case $n=2$ I meant the following setting. Let $f$ be a smooth real function on an open neighbourhood of the unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$ with nonzero gradient everywhere. Then its minimum and maximum on the closed disk are reached on the circle. This is trivial because a critical point inside the disk would yield zero gradient.

Comment: Ah, yes. Makes sense. I was figuring I wasn't understanding the implications of full rank derivative. Nice question!

Comment: it seems to me you could do induction. Consider the unit cube (should be ok as you take an open neighborhood anyway.) I was going to say fix $z$ and consider a horizontal section, but I no longer follow my idea: This map would be from 2D to 2D ( rather than to 1D). Will post anyway, for your consideration.

Comment: @Mirko Thanks! Instead of cubes we could consider simplexes. There may be benefit in triangulating the map; that is an alley that I have not explored and I might need to read up on simplicial topology and de Rham's map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem. Despite originally thinking the result was true and posting a flawed "proof" here, I can now show that it is false. To do this, I will make use of a published result to imply the existence of a counterexample, although a more explicit construction would be desirable.

First, a bit of notation. Regular maps as stated in the question are [submersions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)). A [knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_(mathematics)) is a circle embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (we only consider smoothly embedded knots here), and a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(knot_theory)) $L\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a union $L=\bigcup_{i=1}^nL_i$ of a finite pairwise disjoint set of knots, $\{L_1,L_2,\ldots,L_n\}$.
Given any disjoint pair $L_i,L_j$ of knots, let $lk(L_i,L_j)$ be their [linking number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number). I will use a result by Gilbert Hector and Daniel Peralta-Salas<sup>1</sup>. A subset $L$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is *strongly integrable* (*SI*) if $L=\Phi^{-1}(0)$ for some smooth submersion $\Phi\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, quoting from Hector & Peralta-Salas.

**Theorem 3.6.11.** A link in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is *SI* if and only if
$$
\sum_{j\not=i}lk(L_i,L_j)=1\ mod.\ 2
$$
for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

For example, this condition is satisfied for the [Hopf link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_link) $L=L_1\cup L_2$ for a pair of knots $L_1,L_2$ with linking number 1, so $L$ is *SI*. For our counterexample, we only require that there does exist a link which is *SI*. As links are compact, they are bounded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so, by scaling, we can suppose that $L$ is contained in the open ball of radius $1$. Then, there is a smooth submersion $\Phi\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L=\Phi^{-1}(0)$. So, $0$ is in the image of $\Phi$ restricted to the closed unit ball, but is not in the image of $\Phi$ restricted to the unit sphere, giving the required counterexample.

<sup>1</sup> Hector, G., Peralta-Salas, D: *Integrable embeddings and foliations*, American Journal of Mathematics, **134**, 773-825 (2012), [doi: 10.1353/ajm.2012.0018](http://dx.doi.org/10.1353/ajm.2012.0018), available at [arXiv:1012.4312](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4312).

Comment: thank you very much for this clear argument. (1) I am currently studying the crucial step of building the retract. I notice that in the construction of the vector field $v_Q$ you apply the cutoff function $u,$ which lives in 3 dimensions, to the point $Q$ from a 2-dimensional space. At first I assumed it was a simple typo, but so far I have not been able to come up with a replacement. Could you have a brief look at that? *(to be continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* (2) The inverse image of a point under a regular mapping is a submanifold, which is another way of arguing that the inverse image of any point violating the conjecture would have to consist of a finite number of closed loops.

Comment: Meanwhile I have cleared up (1) by noticing that there are two different uses of the letter $Q$ but they can be separated nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I should be able to tidy up my answer a bit when I have some time. Also, as you say, it is a standard result that the inverse image of a point is a 1d manifold, so I'll update my answer to use that.

Comment: I have accepted the answer because not to do so at this stage would be wholly unfair. If you are still interested in refining it: the double use of the letter $Q$ (first for a point in 3-space and then for a point in 2-space) also occurs earlier on with the letter $P.$

Comment: Ok, there was a mistake in my argument, so the question is still open. I think the proof of 2 may be possible to fix, but its looking a bit complicated.

Comment: Yes please leave it up it is an interesting construction and I am convinced that it can be saved.

Comment: Actually, it can't be saved. The stated result is false, I'm posting the correct result now.

Comment: Wow, I suspected that knots and links might play a role but I never studied them enough, apparently. In the definition of SI, is it necessary that the submersion be global?

Comment: @Justpassingby: The submersion is globally defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$. If it was only defined in a neighbourhood of the link, then it's not too difficult to see that every link would be SI. The range of the submersion need not be all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ though.

Comment: After giving this quite some thought, I have managed to construct an explicit (but, a bit complicated) example, where $\Phi^{-1}(0)$ is a Hopf link. I might come back and post this in a separate answer, as relying on the result stated does not really tell you what such examples might look like.

Comment: I would be very interested in that. Currently trying to wrap my head around Seifert surfaces.